# Run ng-href before ng-blur

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a text input which when focused(read:typed in) shows a dropdown containing an anchor element.
And when the input loses focus, a function is fired using `ng-blur` as follows:

Markup:

```
<input type="text" ng-blur="hideDropdown()" ng-focus="getDropdownData()" />
```

Function:

```
scope.hideDropdown = function() {
    scope.hide_dropdown = true;
}
```

As you can see in the function, I set a variable `hide_dropdown` to true which in turn hides a dropdown containing an anchor element defined as follows:

```
<div ng-hide="hide_dropdown">
    //other li(s)
    <li>
        <a ng-href="remote_url" download>
            Download   
        </a>
    </li>
</div>
```

The problem I am facing is that I need to download a file using the anchor element mentioned. But when I click on the anchor element, instead of downloading the file, `ng-blur` takes precedence and hides the anchor element(using the function) and consequently, the file isn't downloaded.

How can I give more priority to ng-href? I need the file to be downloaded first and *then* `ng-blur` to be fired.

Comment: How come clicking on anchor will fire `blur` event on `input` field? could you eloborate your problem with plunkr?

Comment: Well its like a typeahead. When I type into the text input, a dropdown appears containing the anchor element. And when I click on the anchor element, ng-blur gets fired because the text input loses focus(which is when  ng-blur is fired).

Comment: Then you should have mention this details in your question..please update your question with same information..